# caulk plunger messed up

Tags: caulk

If the "plunger" at the back of the caulk tube is messed up. Will all the caulk become solid?

Or some partial caulk close to the plunger and become solid and "sealed" the gap.

Comment: Either/or. Time will tell.

Comment: Once a tube of stuff is opened, you have a limited time(a few days or a few weeks) to finish it.  A messed up plunger usually just makes the job messier, caulk ends up in back of tube instead of where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

If caulk is leaking past the plunger and out the back of the tube, just throw away the tube. The amount of time you waste cleaning up all the squeeze out will be worth far more (even if you only bill your time at minimum wage) than the purchase price of a new tube.

Once you've made a mess of your caulk gun, you'll kick yourself for being "penny wise and pound foolish" every time you pick it up.

Comment: +1 - cleaning up all the goop which bypassed the plunger and is now all over your caulk gun is a huge PitA and waste of time.